# Adobe Flash and hosting the player with python and wxWidgets

Tags: python, flash, dll, com, wxpython

Does Adobe Flash expose any Automation or hosting interfaces through COM or a DLL in %systemroot%\system32? I'm working with Python and wxWidgets to host a flash application to monitor lunar phases.

http://www.calculatorcat.com/moon_phases/moon_phases.phtml is the application to be hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Flash does expose COM interfaces necessary for hosting it. There is even an [example](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/flash/flash.cpp?view=markup)
showing how to do it in C++ in wxWidgets svn.

Comment: The wxPython demo application (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.0.exe) also includes an example of embedding the flash player.

Comment: As a side note, I was unable to run the demos without the comtypes module. http://sourceforge.net/projects/comtypes/files/ <--- there it is. Just run setup.py

Comment: As another side note, the program is using about 10-15% CPU. I look at the active threads using Procexp64.exe and see that Flash64_10_3_162.ocx!DllUnregisterServer is pretty hot. What further information may be found to see why this thread is so hot? Is there a way to optimize and put that thread to sleep or is it required for the COM object?